# Remove a list of items from another list

Tags: c#

Lets say I have a listBox with 10 elements, and I put the first 4 elements in a List list1, and the rest of elements in another List list2:

```
list2 = listbox.remove(list1);
```

Something like this. Is this posible ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this easily with LINQ:

```
list2 = listbox.Items.Except(list1);
```

However, `Except` needs to compare the items in `list` and the items in `listbox` to produce its results. The above example (default behavior) assumes that the type of the items in the lists are uniquely identified by a reference comparison (which sounds fine in this case).

If the class implements `IEquatable<T>` and/or overrides `Equals`, then `Except` uses that method to test for equality.

Comment: `list2 = listbox.Items.Except(list1)` maybe?